# JavaFX: update UI in separate, non-controller class

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx, nullpointerexception

I have a JavaFX program that launches a task performed by a separate class. I would like to output the status of that task's progress to a `Label` element in the UI. I cannot get this to work. Here is my code:

**Main.java:**

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ui.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Data collector");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Controller.java:**

The label I want to update is created by delcaring globally `@FXML public Label label = new Label();`. Creates a new thread via `new Thread(new Task<Void>() { ... }).start();` to run the `collect_data` method from `TaskRun`. The `TaskRun` class is stated below:

**TaskRun.java:**

```
class TaskRun {
    private Controller ui;

    TaskRun() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ui.fxml"));
        ui = loader.getController();
    }

    void collect_data() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            // do stuff...
            send_progress_to_ui(((float) i / (float)) * 100);
        }
    }

    void send_progress_to_ui(float percent) {
        new Thread(new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                Platform.runLater(() -> ui.label.setText(Float.toString(percent_complete) + "%"));

                return null;
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

I get a `NullPointerException` on the line with the `Platform.runLater(...)`.

So obviously, this method is not going to work. How do I update the UI through this non-controller class `TaskRun`?

Comment: If it's the controller which launching an instance of Taskrun, you can do lie this : new TaskRun(this), and in TaskRun's constructor : 
TaskRun(Controller control){ ui = contro; )
maybe try like this ;), but it depens on where Taskrun is created

Comment: It's created inside a thread within the Controller. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: not sure, but surely i won't work like you did because you'll add 2 instance of controller, it have to be the same, try what i wrote and tell us

Comment: Can you at least tell us what is null and why you expect it not to be null? In general though, doing something to a controller that is linked to a UI you never actually display is not going to achieve anything, even if you get rid of all the exceptions.

Comment: I expected `label` not to be null since it was set to be not null in the controller class.

Comment: But `label` isn't null, is it?

Comment: Nope. I stated that in my controller class I declared `@FXML Label label =  new Label();`

Comment: Creating the `FXMLLoader` alone won't result in the fxml being loaded and thereby the controller being created. This means `ui` is `null`.

Comment: Sort of as an aside: initializing a variable that is annotated `@FXML` is always a mistake.

Comment: @James_D They're supposed to be left uninitialized or initialized in a constructor?

Comment: Left uninitialized, of course. (It's just as much a mistake to initialize them in the constructor as it is to initialize them inline.) The whole point of `@FXML` is that it means the `FXMLLoader` will initialize them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is not really very helpful for what you are trying to do here. Instead of a class that hides the task entirely and creates a thread to run it (which is really inflexible: what if you want to submit the task to an existing `Executor`?), your class should implement the task. Then you can just update the task's progress, which is an observable property:

```
class TaskRun extends Task<Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void call() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            // do stuff...
            updateProgress(i, 100);
        }
        return null ;
    }

}
```

Now in your controller you can just do:

```
TaskRun task = new TaskRun();
task.progressProperty().addListener((obs, oldProgress, newProgress) -> 
    label.setText(String.format("%.2f percent complete", newProgress.doubleValue()*100)));
new Thread(task).start();
```

Alternatively, use a binding instead of the listener:

```
label.textProperty().bind(task.progressProperty().asString("%.2f percent complete"));
```

This gets rid of all the horrendous coupling you have, because now `TaskRun` doesn't need to know anything about the controller class.

Comment: I agree, this design is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the instance of the Controller that updates the UI solves the issue (thanks go to @azro). It turns out that instantiating a controller with `fxmlLoader.getController()` doesn't return the current instance of the controller that is updating the UI.

All that needs to be modified is the `TaskRun` constructor:

```
TaskRun(Controller c) {
    ui = c;
}
```

Where `ui` was the global `Controller` object for `TaskRun` class.

The controller class instantiates a `TaskRun` object within a `Thread`as follows: `TaskRun task = new TaskRun(Controller.this);`

After making these changes, the UI updates as expected.