# Javafx Waiting for a Void Function to End Before Continuing On

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am having trouble with updating the UI of my javafx program. I wish to update the UI once the user has finished a task on a separate window (this window is completed by the use of a void function, nothing is returned and the task i want done is completed fully in this function).

The code below is what I have at the moment. It doesn't work as when the question window is displayed [question.display()] the UI is updated IMMEDIATELY, updateUI() is then not called again:

```
addQuestionButton.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    try {
        Question question = new Question();
        question.display();

        UpdateUI( ... );
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ...
    }
});
```

I've looked into threads however I can't find an answer that involves a void function.

If you can tell me what to do that would be great. I am not that great at coding so any hints, brutal or nice, will be appreciated.

---

I see how this is a very misleading question. Thanks for the comments and believe it or not that actually helped me reach a working solution. showAndwait on the window was enough to stop the function from running before I wanted it to.

To add some context, yes question.display() opened a new window. Show and wait then stops the updateUI() from running

Comment: You didn't give so mush info, so i'll try ^^ In your "Question" class you have to set a method to update your controller 
Look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41601774/javafx-update-ui-in-separate-non-controller-class it will help you surely (BE CAREFUL the right syntax is totaly at the end), your "Question" is the "Task" in the post

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: If you are waiting for a window to close, you probably don't need tasks or threads: just use[`showAndWait`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait--) or a listener for the window's [`onHidden` event](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onHiddenProperty). But you really haven't posted enough code for anyone to figure out what you are doing. Does `Question.display()` show a window??? Please create a [MCVE] and [edit] your question to include it.